# How to mark a folder for deleting after an application closes?

Tags: .net, embedded-resource, temporary-files, resource-cleanup

I'm trying to make a .NET application that is a "complete package". That is, just one .exe file.

To that end I'm embedding my referenced assemblies (and a few unmanaged .DLLs as well) in my .exe. When the .exe is run, these files are extracted into a temporary folder and then loaded in the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event.

But the problem is that I cannot delete these files when the program is done. They are loaded and locked until the process terminates. I don't want to litter the computer with countless temporary DLL files. How do I solve this?

Comment: First of all, why are you creating local file? You could load it in memory using `Assembly.Load`. I'm not sure how to load unmanaged dll; You may need a local file there. Also, there are other better alternates; Have you considered merging the assemblies using [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx)?

Comment: If you're using a temporary folder created with
`string result = Path.GetTempPath();`
then I think you, as a developer, don't have to worry about the contents in this folder. The folder is under control of the OS. Cleaning it up (or not) is up to the system settings.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - OK, Assembly.Load for managed assemblies sounds good. But I still have the unmanaged ones. Hmm... they don't change often however. Perhaps I won't ever change them. I could extract them once to a known location.

Comment: Have you considered deleting the files when you start up the application? Right before you extract the (new) assemblies.

Comment: @Robert - Actually, no. AFAIK it's just a folder. It's the application's responsibility to clean up stuff after itself. However I'm still looking for an authoritative quote about it.

Deleting on start - hmm, yes, that could work.

Comment: I also found another option  - when I create the file I can pass a `FileOptions.DeleteOnClose` flag. Then I just need to keep that handle opened until the end. :)